# How to assign image to the user drawn bezier Path

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using a a bezier path to draw any shape on Image view. When the touch ends , i've closed the path to get the shape .. now i want to achieve the blank area that is inside the bezier path so that i can replace it with another image later on. Rest of the image remains same.

By "Replace with another image " I mean ,I want to assign a new image to the cropped portion or the black hole whatever,.. The result will be like a sticker over an imageView with the path drawn by the user.

I want to crop the content inside the closed path so that when I assign a new image to the path, a new resizable rectangle appears with a new image. Please do not use masking in the new assigned image. I'll have to create a method to resize it's frame, but that too inside the bezierpath. I am attaching the image of desired result too.

I am cropping the content inside the bezier path because i want user to be able to attach another image of his/her choice in that specific area  with resizable rectangular frame. the rectangular frame  can be moved in a screen but its content will only be visible inside the cropped region.

The background image

[image: 1st User draws a bezier path]

When path ends a new image gets assigned to the closed path with the exact frame as closed path.

[image: 2nd grass image gets assigned to path and adjusts its frame]

The frame can then be resized by the user. But the grass image shouldn't move outside the path.

[image: 3rd resizable frame of grass image inside path]

I hope I'm making sense here.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDFGH.jpg it's the same question . i want to get the blank part inside the bezier path ..

Comment: By "Replace another image " I meant ,i'll assign another image to the cropped portion or the black hole whatever,.. The result will be like a sticker over an imageView with the path drawn by the user.

Comment: More like "How to assign image to the user drawn bezier Path"

Comment: i do not want the image view to show only the region that is inside the bezier path ..
1) i want the the content inside the bezier path to be cropped 
2) i want the area outside the bezier path to remain same

Comment: Please show an example. Show the original image, the path, the image you want to show in the path, and the final result.

Comment: I have Added the images of result that i want to achieve.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to *stretch* the image so that it fits in the path?

Comment: the stretch function is another task.. first
1) draw a bezier path on an imageview just like in first image 
2) get the closedpath 
3) assign a new grass Image to closedpath

Comment: @Jeeyaa did u solve the issue ?

Comment: The code didnt work for me

Comment: Found a Good solution for it if you need one . :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're missing a lot of detail about your ultimate goal, but this may get you on your way...

Instead of trying to "cut a hole and fill it" we can:

- overlay the "grass" image in an image view on top of the "street" image
- start with an empty path for the grass "mask" so it is completely clear
- draw the path on the street image
- when the user stops drawing, close the path and set it as the mask-layer path on the grass image view

So, the view hierarchy looks like this (with no mask set on the grass):

[image]

when we set a path for the grass layer mask, it looks like this:

[image]

When running and the user is drawing:

[image]

The user stops drawing, we close the path, and apply it to the grass view:

[image]

Sample code to see that in action...

// **`FillImageView` class** - this will hold the "grass" image, and will apply a layer mask:

```
class FillImageView: UIImageView {
    
    public var userPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath() {
        didSet {
            maskLayer.path = userPath.cgPath
        }
    }
    private let maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        commonInit()
    }
    override init(image: UIImage?) {
        super.init(image: image)
        commonInit()
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
    
}
```

// **`DrawImageView` class** - this will hold the "street" image, and handle drawing the dashed line:

```
class DrawImageView: UIImageView {
    
    // closure used when drawing stops
    public var drawEnded: ((UIBezierPath) -> ())?
    
    // adjust drawing-line-width as desired
    public var lineWidth: CGFloat = 3.0 {
        didSet {
            dashedLineLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        }
    }
    
    public var userPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath() {
        didSet {
            dashedLineLayer.path = userPath.cgPath
        }
    }
    private let dashedLineLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        commonInit()
    }
    override init(image: UIImage?) {
        super.init(image: image)
        commonInit()
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        dashedLineLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        dashedLineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        dashedLineLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        dashedLineLayer.lineDashPattern = [16, 16]
        
        layer.addSublayer(dashedLineLayer)
        
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        userPath.move(to: currentPoint)
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        // add line to our maskPath
        userPath.addLine(to: currentPoint)
        // update the mask layer path
        dashedLineLayer.path = userPath.cgPath
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // close the path
        userPath.close()
        // update the mask
        dashedLineLayer.path = userPath.cgPath
        // closure
        drawEnded?(userPath)
    }
    
}
```

// **`DrawMaskView` class** - manages the `DrawImageView` and the `FillImageView`:

```
class DrawMaskView: UIView {
    
    public var drawImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            drawImageView.image = drawImage
        }
    }
    public var fillImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            fillImageView.image = fillImage
        }
    }
    
    private let drawImageView = DrawImageView()
    private let fillImageView = FillImageView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        [drawImageView, fillImageView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview(v)
        }
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            drawImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            drawImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            drawImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            drawImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),

            fillImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            fillImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            fillImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            fillImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        drawImageView.drawEnded = { [weak self] pth in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            fillImageView.userPath = pth
        }
    }
    
    public func reset() {
        drawImageView.userPath = UIBezierPath()
        fillImageView.userPath = UIBezierPath()
    }
    
}
```

// **simple example view controller** - uses images named "street" and "grass":

```
class ExampleVC: UIViewController {
    
    let testView = DrawMaskView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard let drawImg = UIImage(named: "street"),
              let fillImg = UIImage(named: "grass")
        else {
            fatalError("Could not load images!!!")
        }
        
        testView.drawImage = drawImg
        testView.fillImage = fillImg
        
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(testView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            testView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            testView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -120.0),
        ])
        
        // let's add a Reset button at the bottom
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        btn.setTitle("Reset", for: [])
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(btn)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 60.0),
            btn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -60.0),
            btn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])

        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(reset(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func reset(_ sender: Any?) {
        testView.reset()
    }
    
}
```

---

**Edit**

If you want the "fill" image to scale to fit the path bounds, we can make just a few changes to the above classes...

Instead of making the "grass" image view the same frame as the "street" image view, we will set its frame to the bounds of the bezier path, and then offset the path when we use it as a mask.

// **`FillImageView` class** - same as above

// **`ScaledDrawImageView` class** - mostly the same as above, but we've added a "start" closure so we will start a new path every time (instead of adding paths):

```
class ScaledDrawImageView: UIImageView {
    
    // closure used when drawing starts
    public var drawStart: (() -> ())?
    
    // closure used when drawing stops
    public var drawEnded: ((UIBezierPath) -> ())?
    
    // adjust drawing-line-width as desired
    public var lineWidth: CGFloat = 3.0 {
        didSet {
            dashedLineLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        }
    }
    
    public var userPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath() {
        didSet {
            dashedLineLayer.path = userPath.cgPath
        }
    }
    private let dashedLineLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        commonInit()
    }
    override init(image: UIImage?) {
        super.init(image: image)
        commonInit()
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        dashedLineLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        dashedLineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        dashedLineLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        dashedLineLayer.lineDashPattern = [16, 16]
        
        layer.addSublayer(dashedLineLayer)
        
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        userPath = UIBezierPath()
        userPath.move(to: currentPoint)
        drawStart?()
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        // add line to our maskPath
        userPath.addLine(to: currentPoint)
        // update the mask layer path
        dashedLineLayer.path = userPath.cgPath
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // close the path
        userPath.close()
        // update the mask
        dashedLineLayer.path = userPath.cgPath
        // closure
        drawEnded?(userPath)
    }
    
}
```

// **`ScaledDrawMaskView` class** - adjusts the frame of the "grass" image view and transforms the path:

```
class ScaledDrawMaskView: UIView {

    public var drawImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            drawImageView.image = drawImage
        }
    }
    public var fillImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            fillImageView.image = fillImage
        }
    }

    private let drawImageView = ScaledDrawImageView()
    private let fillImageView = FillImageView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        addSubview(drawImageView)
        addSubview(fillImageView)
        
        drawImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            drawImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            drawImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            drawImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            drawImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        // subImageView will NOT use constraints
        
        drawImageView.drawStart = { [weak self] in
            self?.fillImageView.userPath = UIBezierPath()
        }
        drawImageView.drawEnded = { [weak self] pth in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.fillImageView.frame = pth.bounds
            let tr = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -pth.bounds.origin.x, y: -pth.bounds.origin.y)
            pth.apply(tr)
            fillImageView.userPath = pth
        }

    }
    
    public func reset() {
        drawImageView.userPath = UIBezierPath()
        fillImageView.userPath = UIBezierPath()
    }
    
}
```

// **simple example view controller** - same as above, except we use `ScaledDrawMaskView` instead of `DrawMaskView`:

```
class ExampleVC: UIViewController {
    
    //let testView = DrawMaskView()
    let testView = ScaledDrawMaskView()

    // everything else is the same
```

Now, using this image as the "grass" image, so we can see the scaling:

[image]

We get this output for a few different path shapes:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do not want to cut the grass image. rather I want to adjust the whole grass image into the frame of the path drawn by the user...
The grass image should resize and fit into the path

Comment: @Jeeyaa - see the **Edit** in my answer. For future reference, it's a good idea to try and give a fully detailed description of what you're trying to do, so we aren't *guessing*.

Comment: Can you help me with getting the image in a resizable rectangular box too ?

Comment: @Jeeyaa - don't edit your question with *"here is something else I'm trying to do"* ... mark the answer as **Accepted** and then post a new question with your new task.

Comment: ok. but somebody else edited this question .

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this, you can follow these steps:

**Create a Mask Image from Bezier Path:**
After the user completes drawing the path, you can create a mask image from the Bezier path. This mask image will have a transparent area inside the path and opaque outside.

```
// Assuming `bezierPath` is your completed UIBezierPath
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath

let maskImage = UIImage.image(fromLayer: maskLayer)
```

**Apply the Mask to the Original Image:**
Apply the mask image to the original image so that you have the content of the original image inside the user-drawn path and the rest outside the path.

```
let maskedImage = originalImage.applyMask(maskImage: maskImage)
```

**Overlay the Result with Another Image:**
Now you can overlay the maskedImage with another image (your sticker) to achieve the desired effect.

```
let overlayedImage = maskedImage.overlayWith(image: stickerImage)
```

**Here are the helper extensions and methods you can use:**

```
extension UIImage {
    func applyMask(maskImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        let maskRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return self
        }
        
        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        
        context.clip(to: maskRect, mask: maskImage.cgImage!)
        draw(in: maskRect)
        
        let maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        return maskedImage ?? self
    }
    
    func overlayWith(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        
        draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
        image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
        
        let overlayedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        return overlayedImage ?? self
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    static func image(fromLayer layer: CALayer) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, 0)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return nil
        }
        
        layer.render(in: context)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        return image
    }
}
```